# Why Picasso taking time to display image in ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I'm using Picasso for my app. Its working fine but taking too much time to display image into ImageView.Can anyone please tell me what is the reason and how can I fix it?

I'm using this code:

```
Picasso.with(image.getContext())
                        .load(imageIds[currentIndex])
                        .transform(new BitmapTransform(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT))
                        .skipMemoryCache()
                        .resize(size, size)
                        .centerInside()
                        .into(image);
```

where MAX_WIDTH and MAX_HEIGHT are declare as:

```
    private static final int MAX_WIDTH = 1000;
    private static final int MAX_HEIGHT = 700;
```

and the code is:

```
    public class BitmapTransform implements Transformation {

        int maxWidth;
        int maxHeight;

        public BitmapTransform(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
            this.maxHeight = maxHeight;
        }

        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
            int targetWidth, targetHeight;
            double aspectRatio;

            if (source.getWidth() > source.getHeight()) {
                targetWidth = maxWidth;
                aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
                targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);
            } else {
                targetHeight = maxHeight;
                aspectRatio = (double) source.getWidth() / (double) source.getHeight();
                targetWidth = (int) (targetHeight * aspectRatio);
            }

            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
            if (result != source) {
                source.recycle();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return maxWidth + "x" + maxHeight;
        }

    };
```

After adding setLoggingEnabled(true) the log is as follow:
can't show the complete log as due to words limit here.

```
08-12 05:20:52.270      383-406/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun
08-12 05:20:56.670      383-406/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun
08-12 05:21:04.650      383-398/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun appid=10055 user=-1: uninstall pkg
08-12 05:21:04.950      383-406/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ Package com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun codePath changed from /data/app/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun-2.apk to /data/app/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
08-12 05:21:04.980      383-406/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ Running dexopt on: com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun
08-12 05:21:08.270      383-406/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Code path for pkg : com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun changing from /data/app/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun-2.apk to /data/app/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun-1.apk
08-12 05:21:08.270      383-406/system_process W/PackageManager﹕ Resource path for pkg : com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun changing from /data/app/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun-2.apk to /data/app/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun-1.apk
08-12 05:21:08.310      383-398/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun appid=10055 user=-1: update pkg
08-12 05:21:08.850      383-406/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Force stopping com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun appid=10055 user=0: pkg removed
08-12 05:21:09.450      383-383/system_process D/BackupManagerService﹕ Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
08-12 05:21:09.800      383-383/system_process D/BackupManagerService﹕ Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
08-12 05:21:17.090      383-620/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/.logo} from pid 882
08-12 05:21:17.700      383-565/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun for activity com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/.logo: pid=892 uid=10055 gids={50055}
08-12 05:21:20.370      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun W/Settings﹕ Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
08-12 05:21:20.580      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
08-12 05:21:20.830      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7f45bb0, tid 892
08-12 05:21:21.390      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-12 05:21:21.490      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-12 05:21:23.520      383-397/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/.logo: +6s87ms
08-12 05:21:23.600      383-620/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/.Main} from pid 892
08-12 05:21:24.900      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 125K, 7% free 3195K/3404K, paused 81ms, total 95ms
08-12 05:21:25.020      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 10.050MB for 7200016-byte allocation
08-12 05:21:25.180      892-901/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 3% free 10221K/10436K, paused 150ms, total 150ms
08-12 05:21:26.070      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
08-12 05:21:26.520      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-12 05:21:29.120      383-397/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ This window was lost: Window{b404c400 u0 com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun.logo}
08-12 05:21:29.120      383-397/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ mDisplayId=0 mSession=Session{b4008bc8 892:u0a10055} mClient=android.os.BinderProxy@b4004d38
    mOwnerUid=10055 mShowToOwnerOnly=true package=com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun appop=NONE
    mAttrs=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#120 ty=1 fl=#1810100 pfl=0x8 wanim=0x1030001}
    Requested w=1200 h=1824 mLayoutSeq=56
    mBaseLayer=21000 mSubLayer=0 mAnimLayer=21005+0=21005 mLastLayer=21010
    mToken=AppWindowToken{b40f75e8 token=Token{b3fa80a8 ActivityRecord{b4022c80 u0 com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/.logo t2}}}
    mRootToken=AppWindowToken{b40f75e8 token=Token{b3fa80a8 ActivityRecord{b4022c80 u0 com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/.logo t2}}}
    mAppToken=AppWindowToken{b40f75e8 token=Token{b3fa80a8 ActivityRecord{b4022c80 u0 com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/.logo t2}}}
    mViewVisibility=0x0 mHaveFrame=true mObscured=false
    mSeq=0 mSystemUiVisibility=0x0
    mGivenContentInsets=[0,0][0,0] mGivenVisibleInsets=[0,0][0,0]
    mConfiguration={1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw600dp w600dp h887dp 320dpi lrg port finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h s.5}
    mHasSurface=true mShownFrame=[0.0,0.0][1200.0,1824.0] isReadyForDisplay()=false
    mFrame=[0,0][1200,1824] last=[0,0][1200,1824]
    mSystemDecorRect=[0,50][1200,1824] last=[0,50][1200,1824]
    Frames: containing=[0,0][1200,1824] parent=[0,0][1200,1824]
    display=[0,0][1200,1824] overscan=[0,0][1200,1920]
    content=[0,50][1200,1824] visible=[0,50][1200,1824]
    decor=[0,50][1200,1824]
    Cur insets: overscan=[0,0][0,0] content=[0,50][0,0] visible=[0,50][0,0]
    Lst insets: overscan=[0,0][0,0] content=[0,50][0,0] visible=[0,50][0,0]
    WindowStateAnimator{b40e85e0 com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun.logo}:
    mSurface=Surface(name=com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun.logo)
    mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN mLastHidden=true
    Surface: shown=false layer=21010 alpha=1.0 rect=(0.0,0.0) 1200.0 x 1824.0
    mGlobalScale=1.0 mDsDx=1.0 mDtDx=0.0 mDsDy=0.0 mDtDy=1.0
    mExiting=false mRemoveOnExit=false mDestroying=true mRemoved=false
08-12 05:21:29.180      383-397/system_process V/WindowManager﹕ #1: Token{b4008718 ActivityRecord{b40f9f48 u0 com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/.Main t2}}
08-12 05:21:29.180      383-397/system_process V/WindowManager﹕ #5: Window{b40909f8 u0 com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun.Main}
08-12 05:21:30.620      383-397/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/.Main: +6s697ms
08-12 05:21:30.870      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7K, 2% free 12020K/12196K, paused 52ms, total 61ms
08-12 05:21:35.300      383-656/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun.AA cmp=com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/.aa} from pid 892
08-12 05:21:36.190      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2138K, 19% free 10318K/12588K, paused 73ms, total 86ms
08-12 05:21:36.340      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 14.140MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-12 05:21:36.460      892-901/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 14% free 14413K/16688K, paused 117ms, total 117ms
08-12 05:21:37.760      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 14% free 14413K/16688K, paused 86ms, total 87ms
08-12 05:21:37.920      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 18.139MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-12 05:21:38.020      892-901/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 18509K/20788K, paused 103ms, total 103ms
08-12 05:21:39.390      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 18510K/20788K, paused 100ms, total 103ms
08-12 05:21:39.540      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 22.140MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-12 05:21:40.250      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 22606K/24888K, paused 91ms, total 92ms
08-12 05:21:40.280      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  enqueued     [R1]+5ms
08-12 05:21:40.290      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      executing    [R1]+18ms
08-12 05:21:40.990      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-12 05:21:44.180      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 43K, 10% free 22591K/24888K, paused 125ms, total 126ms
08-12 05:21:44.380      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 26.125MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-12 05:21:44.470      383-397/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun/.aa: +9s74ms
08-12 05:21:44.570      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 26686K/28988K, paused 115ms, total 118ms
08-12 05:21:45.120      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      decoded      [R1]+4847ms
08-12 05:21:45.130      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  batched      [R1]+4851ms for completion
08-12 05:21:45.340      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  delivered    [R1]+5s
08-12 05:21:45.350      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        completed    [R1]+5s from DISK
08-12 05:21:46.490      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-12 05:21:49.410      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        created      [R2] Request{2130837592 1000x700 resize(837,837) centerInside}
08-12 05:21:50.050      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  enqueued     [R2]+678ms
08-12 05:21:50.380      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      executing    [R2]+1006ms
08-12 05:21:51.620      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4109K, 10% free 22597K/24852K, paused 70ms, total 72ms
08-12 05:21:51.670      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 26.130MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-12 05:21:52.110      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 26692K/28952K, paused 64ms, total 64ms
08-12 05:21:52.110      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      decoded      [R2]+2737ms
08-12 05:21:52.190      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 8% free 26692K/28952K, paused 70ms, total 70ms
08-12 05:21:52.220      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.803MB for 2802292-byte allocation
08-12 05:21:52.300      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 29429K/31692K, paused 73ms, total 73ms
08-12 05:21:52.530      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R2]+3155ms
08-12 05:21:52.580      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R2]+3206ms from custom transformations
08-12 05:21:52.590      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  batched      [R2]+3209ms for completion
08-12 05:21:52.800      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        completed    [R2]+3418ms from DISK
08-12 05:21:52.830      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  delivered    [R2]+3453ms
08-12 05:21:53.360      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-12 05:21:55.170      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        created      [R3] Request{2130837594 1000x700 resize(837,837) centerInside}
08-12 05:21:55.210      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      executing    [R3]+23ms
08-12 05:21:55.360      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  enqueued     [R3]+16ms
08-12 05:21:56.190      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8760K, 10% free 22598K/24852K, paused 95ms, total 106ms
08-12 05:21:56.310      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 26.132MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-12 05:21:56.950      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 26694K/28952K, paused 70ms, total 70ms
08-12 05:21:56.950      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      decoded      [R3]+1782ms
08-12 05:21:57.030      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 8% free 26694K/28952K, paused 74ms, total 75ms
08-12 05:21:57.070      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.804MB for 2802292-byte allocation
08-12 05:21:57.140      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 29430K/31692K, paused 73ms, total 73ms
08-12 05:21:57.380      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R3]+2205ms
08-12 05:21:57.430      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R3]+2253ms from custom transformations
08-12 05:21:57.430      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  batched      [R3]+2258ms for completion
08-12 05:21:57.810      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        completed    [R3]+2640ms from DISK
08-12 05:21:57.970      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  delivered    [R3]+2648ms
08-12 05:21:58.370      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-12 05:22:00.430      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        created      [R4] Request{2130837601 1000x700 resize(837,837) centerInside}
08-12 05:22:00.460      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  enqueued     [R4]+16ms
08-12 05:22:00.640      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      executing    [R4]+212ms
08-12 05:22:02.190      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8760K, 10% free 22599K/24852K, paused 96ms, total 103ms
08-12 05:22:02.290      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 26.133MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-12 05:22:04.520      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 26694K/28952K, paused 78ms, total 90ms
08-12 05:22:04.520      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      decoded      [R4]+4097ms
08-12 05:22:04.660      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 8% free 26694K/28952K, paused 99ms, total 101ms
08-12 05:22:04.920      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.805MB for 2802292-byte allocation
08-12 05:22:05.030      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 29431K/31692K, paused 100ms, total 112ms
08-12 05:22:06.080      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R4]+5s
08-12 05:22:06.230      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R4]+5s from custom transformations
08-12 05:22:06.290      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  batched      [R4]+5s for completion
08-12 05:22:06.440      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  delivered    [R4]+6s
08-12 05:22:06.450      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        completed    [R4]+6s from DISK
08-12 05:22:07.010      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-12 05:22:11.474      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        created      [R5] Request{2130837604 1000x700 resize(837,837) centerInside}
08-12 05:22:11.814      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  enqueued     [R5]+257ms
08-12 05:22:11.824      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      executing    [R5]+277ms
08-12 05:22:12.994      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8760K, 10% free 22599K/24852K, paused 74ms, total 74ms
08-12 05:22:13.044      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 26.133MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-12 05:22:13.474      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 26694K/28952K, paused 63ms, total 63ms
08-12 05:22:13.474      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      decoded      [R5]+2000ms
08-12 05:22:13.554      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 8% free 26695K/28952K, paused 68ms, total 68ms
08-12 05:22:13.584      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.805MB for 2802292-byte allocation
08-12 05:22:13.664      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 29431K/31692K, paused 73ms, total 74ms
08-12 05:22:13.894      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R5]+2422ms
08-12 05:22:13.944      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R5]+2471ms from custom transformations
08-12 05:22:13.954      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  batched      [R5]+2474ms for completion
08-12 05:22:14.164      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        completed    [R5]+2690ms from DISK
08-12 05:22:14.414      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  delivered    [R5]+2936ms
08-12 05:22:14.744      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-12 05:22:15.814      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        created      [R6] Request{2130837606 1000x700 resize(837,837) centerInside}
08-12 05:22:15.824      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  enqueued     [R6]+27ms
08-12 05:22:15.824      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      executing    [R6]+31ms
08-12 05:22:16.524      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8760K, 10% free 22599K/24852K, paused 73ms, total 74ms
08-12 05:22:16.574      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 26.133MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-12 05:22:17.014      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 26695K/28952K, paused 62ms, total 63ms
08-12 05:22:17.014      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      decoded      [R6]+1220ms
08-12 05:22:17.084      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 8% free 26695K/28952K, paused 67ms, total 68ms
08-12 05:22:17.124      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.805MB for 2802292-byte allocation
08-12 05:22:17.194      892-901/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 29431K/31692K, paused 75ms, total 75ms
08-12 05:22:17.444      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R6]+1646ms
08-12 05:22:17.504      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R6]+1706ms from custom transformations
08-12 05:22:17.514      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  batched      [R6]+1710ms for completion
08-12 05:22:17.744      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  delivered    [R6]+1922ms
08-12 05:22:17.754      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        completed    [R6]+1917ms from DISK
08-12 05:22:18.334      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-12 05:22:19.574      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        created      [R7] Request{2130837607 1000x700 resize(837,837) centerInside}
08-12 05:22:19.584      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  enqueued     [R7]+94ms
08-12 05:22:19.754      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      executing    [R7]+100ms
08-12 05:22:20.224      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8760K, 10% free 22600K/24852K, paused 76ms, total 76ms
08-12 05:22:20.274      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 26.133MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-12 05:22:20.344      892-901/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 26695K/28952K, paused 70ms, total 70ms
08-12 05:22:21.004      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      decoded      [R7]+1507ms
08-12 05:22:21.074      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 8% free 26695K/28952K, paused 69ms, total 70ms
08-12 05:22:21.104      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.805MB for 2802292-byte allocation
08-12 05:22:21.174      892-901/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 29432K/31692K, paused 72ms, total 72ms
08-12 05:22:21.424      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R7]+1931ms
08-12 05:22:21.474      892-917/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R7]+1982ms from custom transformations
08-12 05:22:21.474      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  batched      [R7]+1986ms for completion
08-12 05:22:21.684      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        completed    [R7]+2195ms from DISK
08-12 05:22:21.714      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  delivered    [R7]+2202ms
08-12 05:22:24.014      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        created      [R8] Request{2130837609 1000x700 resize(837,837) centerInside}
08-12 05:22:24.024      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  enqueued     [R8]+29ms
08-12 05:22:24.024      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      executing    [R8]+35ms
08-12 05:22:24.694      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8759K, 10% free 22600K/24852K, paused 85ms, total 85ms
08-12 05:22:24.744      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 26.134MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-12 05:22:25.244      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 26695K/28952K, paused 64ms, total 65ms
08-12 05:22:25.244      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      decoded      [R8]+1252ms
08-12 05:22:25.314      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 8% free 26695K/28952K, paused 68ms, total 68ms
08-12 05:22:25.354      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.806MB for 2802292-byte allocation
08-12 05:22:25.434      892-901/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 29432K/31692K, paused 75ms, total 75ms
08-12 05:22:25.684      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R8]+1689ms
08-12 05:22:25.734      892-968/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R8]+1736ms from custom transformations
08-12 05:22:25.734      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  batched      [R8]+1741ms for completion
08-12 05:22:25.944      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  delivered    [R8]+1945ms
08-12 05:22:25.974      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        completed    [R8]+1963ms from DISK
08-12 05:22:28.804      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        created      [R9] Request{2130837611 1000x700 resize(837,837) centerInside}
08-12 05:22:28.954      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  enqueued     [R9]+13ms
08-12 05:22:28.974      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      executing    [R9]+154ms
08-12 05:22:29.414      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8759K, 10% free 22600K/24852K, paused 74ms, total 75ms
08-12 05:22:29.464      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 26.134MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-12 05:22:29.534      892-901/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 26696K/28952K, paused 76ms, total 76ms
08-12 05:22:29.904      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      decoded      [R9]+1101ms
08-12 05:22:29.974      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 8% free 26695K/28952K, paused 69ms, total 70ms
08-12 05:22:30.004      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.806MB for 2802292-byte allocation
08-12 05:22:30.084      892-901/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 29432K/31692K, paused 73ms, total 73ms
08-12 05:22:30.314      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R9]+1519ms
08-12 05:22:30.364      892-912/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Hunter      transformed  [R9]+1567ms from custom transformations
08-12 05:22:30.364      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  batched      [R9]+1571ms for completion
08-12 05:22:30.584      892-892/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Main        completed    [R9]+1780ms from DISK
08-12 05:22:30.774      892-910/com.kidooz.kidooz_abcfun D/Picasso﹕ Dispatcher  delivered    [R9]+1773ms
```

Comment: How big is the image? Are you downloading the image? If so, how good is your internet connection?

Comment: Possibly because your internet connection is slow or image size is large.

Comment: I'm not downloading the images they are from drawable.Does it need high speed net? I don't think so.@Aniruddha

Comment: i have tried your code and it works. try adding `setLoggingEnabled(true)` to your `Picasso` instance and post the log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'll explain expensive actions line by line:

```
.load(imageIds[currentIndex])
```

As mentioned above, this will load your image from Internet or filesystem. In first case download time depends on image size and Internet connection quality. In second case it depends only on image size but remember that disk operations are also performance-expensive.

```
.transform(new BitmapTransform(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT))
```

Here you are applying a transformation to your new bitmap which need to allocate additional memory to create scaled bitmap.

```
.resize(size, size)
```

Here you are resizing image again - I'm not familiar  with Picasso's `resize` implementation but I believe it is also needs additional memory. Actually why do you resize image twice? Maybe you should think about how to combine two resize operations in one transformation.

Other stuff hasn't serious impact to performance.

---